# Explode column of DataFrame and fill contents of other column with custom value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to replicate the contents of the open_hours column for as many times as the list contained in it. On doing that, I want the hour column to be populated with each of the open_hours and the counts to be populated with the actual counts if the hour is in open_hours and we have counts for it, otherwise to populate it with a value that is a result of a function of the current row. Explode might not be the answer but this is what I want to do:

```
id counts hour  open_hours
 1    2    19  [19, 20, 21]  

Desired output:
id counts hour  open_hours
1    2    19    [19, 20, 21] 
1    x1   20    [19, 20, 21]
1    x2   21    [19, 20, 21]
```

where x the output of a function that takes each row as input and produces an output during the explode. An example could be:

```
def func(row):
    return row['id']/row['counts'] if hour in open_hours else 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated per comments:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2],'counts':[2,3],'hour':[19,20],'open_hours':[[19,20,21],[19,20,21]]})

dfc = (
    df[["id", "counts", "open_hours"]]
    .explode("open_hours")
    .rename(columns={"open_hours": "hour"})
    .assign(open_hours=df["open_hours"])
)
# dfc = dfc.reset_index(drop=True)
dfc['counts'] = dfc['counts'].mask(dfc.duplicated(['id','counts']), 0)
print(dfc)
```

Output:

```
   id  counts hour    open_hours
0   1       2   19  [19, 20, 21]
0   1       0   20  [19, 20, 21]
0   1       0   21  [19, 20, 21]
1   2       3   19  [19, 20, 21]
1   2       0   20  [19, 20, 21]
1   2       0   21  [19, 20, 21]
```

---

Try this:

```
dfc = (
    df[["id", "counts", "open_hours"]]
    .explode("open_hours")
    .rename(columns={"open_hours": "hour"})
    .assign(open_hours=df["open_hours"])
)

dfc["counts"] = dfc["counts"].mask(
    dfc["counts"].duplicated(), "x" + dfc["counts"].duplicated().cumsum().astype(str)
)

dfc
```

Output:

```
   id counts hour    open_hours
0   1      2   19  [19, 20, 21]
0   1     x1   20  [19, 20, 21]
0   1     x2   21  [19, 20, 21]
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, how can the result of Counts column be a function of the operation that happens?

Comment: Yeah x is not a string. I want it to dynamically be the output of a function that takes place during the explode operation

Comment: @azal... sorry, I don't understand your request for the counts column.

Comment: Let me rephrase: how can the counts value (which is not known for hour=20 and hour=21) get a number equal to something like (row['counts'] for hour=19) / row['id'] of specific row.

Comment: LOL @azal  Sorry... That didn't help me at all.   Forgive my denseness.

Comment: No worries, I'll give it a shot again with a simpler example. How could I set x1 and x2 equal to 0? --I do not have counts for those hours. (I want that to happen during the pipeline of transformations)

Comment: If you sample ahs this one record, the you can use use `mask` and `duplicated` like I've done to append 'x' to the count,  `dfc['counts'] = dfc['counts'].mask(dfc['counts'].duplicated(),0)`

Comment: Now, you have multiple records, you need to do use `groupby(level=0)` or `groupby('id')`.

Comment: I do not think the 'mask' approach will work for more than 1 unique ids

Comment: You're right, can you showcase an example ?

Comment: Couldn't something like     .assign(counts=df.apply(lambda x: x['count'] if x['hour'] in x['open_hours'] else 0)) work.   ? ? ?